# GPS application works on emualtor but not on my phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

My basic location application doesent work on my Galaxy A20 running API 29 but works fine on all my emuultors running the same API. im not sure what the problem could be as im not experianced with LOGCAT but the error states as following:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference.

THE ERROR IS ON LINE 117 on my project (At the end). But ive highlighted it here

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1){


            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ,0 ,0 , locationListener);

            }


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Marker in user house"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this , new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION} , 1);

        }
        else{

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER , 0 , 0 , locationListener);

            Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()); // ◅ THE ERROR OCCOURS HERE********
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Marker in user house"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));


        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your phone has not managed to get a GPS fix yet. Check if lastKnowLocation is null before using it, and test the app outside where your phone can "see" the sky.